# PHP: PDO Update Record Not Working (No Error)

Tags: php

**The Goal:**

I have a file called Edit.php that should allow me to edit a record based on the ID pulled from the previous page using the GET variable ex edit.php?id=14

The first half of my script works fine. My SELECT query fetches the user data based on the GET ID and places them into the Edit User fields to show what the current values are.

**Bit that doesn't work:**

I then used a similar statement to my login.php that has been edited to use UPDATE etc in order to overrite the current pulled values.

Despite showing no errors and redirecting upon clicking submit, no data is changed.

**Note:**
Though I'm still learning, I don't think it's a connection issue simply because all my other code (register, login, select, etc) is working fine, it's just UPDATE that giving me issues.

Any help or ideas would be appreciated! I'd rather figure out and understand the issue than start over.

CONNECTION FILE

```php
<?php

$host = 'localhost';
$db   = 'cms';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$charset = 'utf8mb4';

$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset";
$options = [
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
];
try {
     $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $options);
} catch (\PDOException $e) {
     throw new \PDOException($e->getMessage(), (int)$e->getCode());
}

?>
```

EDIT.PHP <-- the issue

```php
<?php
include 'admin-header.php';
include 'db.php';
$id = $_GET['id'];
?>

<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = ?";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute([$id]);
$user = $stmt->fetch();
?>


<!-- main content start -->

    <div class="container">
        <form action="edit.php" method="post" class="form">
            <h1>Edit user</h1>
            <label for="username">New username:</label><br>
            <input type="text" name="username" value="<?= $user['user_name']; ?>"><br><br>

            <label for="Password">New password:</label><br>
            <input type="password" name="password" value="<?= $user['user_pass']; ?>"><br><br>

            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update">
        </form>
    </div>

    <?php 
            if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {

            //hash given password
            $hash = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

            $sql = "UPDATE users SET user_name = ?, user_pass = ? WHERE user_id = ?";
            $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->execute([$_POST['username'], $hash, $id]);

            header("Location:users.php");
        }

    ?>

<!-- main content end -->
<?php include 'admin-footer.php' ?>
```

Comment: So you mean that after submitting the edit, nothing seems to update, correct? If so, then the deal is that the edit is a POST to itself, but the GET will not have an id at that point, so after post-ing, no match is found for the update query. You can echo the id (after the point of retrieving) to see if this is the situation.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. First off, yes, upon clicking submit, nothing is changed and no error shows.Second, echoing $id after the Select query (retrieval?) does show the correct ID (14 in this case). In fact, echoing $id anywhere on the page (before clicking submit) shows a value.

Comment: Right, but what does the id show after submit? (when it loads back to the same page)

Comment: Ah my bad, Undefined index: id on line 4, the URL becomes edit.php rather than edit.php?=14 (I removed the header redirect...)

Comment: I guess my issue is, how can I keep the $_GET value (id number) upon submit after already using it to pull current data?

Comment: You might not need the ID, you could possibly update based on the username, assuming the usernames are unique, after POST.

Comment: Fixed: Pulled the ID into it's own hidden field and stored the value in a POST variable upon submit.

Comment: That can work too. However, know that approach has security implications.

Comment: I'm not sure what else to try :/ My original way should have worked according to the guide I was following.

Do those implications matter if the whole thing is wrapped in a secure login with no outside-registering? If not, what is the best practice for what I'm after?
Thanks

Comment: Well, it depends. If there is a secure login, and only (ethical/trustworthy) admins can make changes, then it may likely ok. However, if this edit is a link that ANY user can use, then that could be trouble.